# UIButton highlight color with UIButton.ConfigurationUpdateHandler in iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to implement `UIButton.Configuration` to design my buttons in iOS 15 and I'm running into an issue trying to set the background color for the highlighted state. I'm using the `UIButton.ConfigurationUpdateHandler`, which successfully changes the background color on state changes:

```
let handler: UIButton.ConfigurationUpdateHandler = { button in
           switch button.state {
           case [.selected, .highlighted]:
               button.configuration?.baseBackgroundColor = .buttonHighlightColor
           case .selected:
               button.configuration?.baseBackgroundColor = .buttonHighlightColor
           case .highlighted:
               button.configuration?.baseBackgroundColor = .buttonHighlightColor
           case .disabled:
               button.configuration?.baseBackgroundColor = .buttonDisabledColor
           default:
               button.configuration?.baseBackgroundColor = .buttonDefaultColor
           }
    }
```

While the background color changes, it seems there is still some sort of white semi-transparent overlay on top of the button when highlighted:

[image]

Left is what the button looks like when highlighted now, right is what the highlight color should look like.

I first thought this might be because the button type is **System** but even with **Custom** the problem persists. Never had this issue before using `UIButton.Configuration`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have just found the solution, in case someone else has this issue:

Instead of `button.configuration?.baseBackgroundColor` I had to use `button.configuration?.background.backgroundColor` and the white overlay is gone.